# React Native android app build successful but won't install on phone

Tags: android, react-native

I have been running React Native android app on my android phone.
This morning I ran the debug and release APK commands to share the APK with a friend. After that, the normal 'nom start' command won't install the app on my phone which I have already deleted the APK in the phone. Here is the terminal output stating build is successful.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 19s
245 actionable tasks: 11 executed, 234 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "RNOMPLHA0312091"...
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity }
```

But on my phone no app is getting installed. I am not sure what to do next. I have already run the

```
./gradlew clean
```

Is there anything more I can do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sometimes you need to delete the app with adb ```adb -d shell pm uninstall com.my.package.name```